# Mark an elements with CSS in order to later detect them with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using CSS selectors to match certain elements and I would like to detect those elements with javascript.
I figured out I can set the color in css of those element and later retrieve them by color.
The problem is style.backgroundColor returns only the if inline style is set.

Here is my try
http://jsfiddle.net/qUDjb/29/

CSS

```
div{background-color: lightgrey;}
```

JS

```
alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor);
```

Is there a way to make color detection to work or maybe somebody has a better idea on how to detect affected elements (by css selectors)?

I prefer not to use jquery for this.

Comment: Why not just set a class to the elements?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Set a class `.lightgrey` and later search for this class to find all the elements to delete

Comment: If you change your mind and will use jQuery, you can use: $('#myDiv').css('background-color')

Comment: This is a very specific situation.
Changing the html is not an option.
All I am trying is to detect the elements affected by a quite large list of css selectors.

Any other idea about achieving this will be also accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`element.style` only returns inline style declarations (or declarations added in JS using `elements.style['foo'] = "bar"`. It isn't always the rule that's applied by the browser, for example a CSS declaration with `!important` can override inline styles. You can also have multiple CSS declarations that overwrite one another and the browser decides which one to apply using CSS selector precedence rules.

To get what rule has really been applied you should use `getComputedStyle` method: http://jsfiddle.net/qUDjb/31/

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv"))['background-color']
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) on getComputedStyle

EDIT: if you want to get elements by background color it wouldn't really be the best way, but it's possible to get a collection of elements, then filter by the computed style value: http://jsfiddle.net/qUDjb/36/

**CSS**

```
p:nth-child(2n) {
     background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

**JS**

```
var getElementsByBackgroundColor = function( collection, color ){
    // convert the color string to the format used by browser
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.backgroundColor = color;
    var computedColor = div.style.backgroundColor;

    // compare computed background color and return matching elements
    return [].slice.call( collection ).filter( function( item ){
       return window.getComputedStyle( item )['background-color'] == computedColor;
    });
}
console.log( getElementsByBackgroundColor( document.querySelectorAll('p'), 'lightgrey') );
```